# time attack on bash program with usleep() inside

Tags: bash, dynamic-linking, usleep

I have a little hackme where I have to get the password with brute force. In the program is the function usleep(); when I have the right length and it is changing when one letter is right.
It would not be a problem, but the sleep time is about one minute and this is quite a long time. 
Is there a way to make the usleep timer faster?

ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs)

Comment: Posting some code specific to the problem would be helpful for anyone trying to answer your question. If it's not to much trouble, the highest quality questions abstract the problem so it is more generally applicable to other users seeking a similar answer.

Comment: LD_PRELOAD a library that overrides usleep

Answer (score 4):

## Method 1

You can override library functions with a `LD_PRELOAD` directive.

There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/) and [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial-part-2/) to get you started with this.

Suppose you have the following program code, which is then compiled to a binary elf file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for usleep() */

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   printf("Entry point. We'll now wait 10 seconds.\n");
   system("date  +\"%H:%M:%S\""); //Output time

   usleep(10*1000*1000);

   printf("Woke up again.\n");
   system("date  +\"%H:%M:%S\""); //Output time
 
   return 0;
}
```

Running it normally would give you

```
root@kali:~/so# gcc -o prog prog.c
root@kali:~/so# ./prog 
Entry point. We'll now wait 10 seconds.
20:31:10
Woke up again.
20:31:20
```

Now write your own version of `usleep()`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int usleep(useconds_t usec){
   printf("Nope, you're not sleeping today :)\n");
 
   return 0;
}
```

Compile it as a shared library.

```
root@kali:~/so# gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o usleep_override.so usleep_override.c
```

Now preload that library function before executing the original program.

```
root@kali:~/so# LD_PRELOAD=./usleep_override.so ./prog
Entry point. We'll now wait 10 seconds.
20:35:28
Nope, you're not sleeping today :)
Woke up again.
20:35:28
```

As you can see when looking at the `date` output, it executed the hooked function instead of the original and then immediatly returned.

## Method 2

Modify the binary. In particular, modify the instructions sothat the `usleep()` function is not executed.

When we dump the instructions of the `main()` function of `prog` with `objdump`, we get:

```
root@kali:~/so# objdump -d -Mintel prog | grep  -A20 "<main>"
0000000000400596 <main>:
  400596:   55                      push   rbp
  400597:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40059a:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
  40059e:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
  4005a1:   48 89 75 f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
  4005a5:   bf 68 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x400668
  4005aa:   e8 a1 fe ff ff          call   400450 <puts@plt>
  4005af:   bf 90 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x400690
  4005b4:   e8 a7 fe ff ff          call   400460 <system@plt>
  4005b9:   bf 80 96 98 00          mov    edi,0x989680
  4005be:   e8 cd fe ff ff          call   400490 <usleep@plt>
  4005c3:   bf a2 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x4006a2
  4005c8:   e8 83 fe ff ff          call   400450 <puts@plt>
  4005cd:   bf 90 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x400690
  4005d2:   e8 89 fe ff ff          call   400460 <system@plt>
  4005d7:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4005dc:   c9                      leave  
  4005dd:   c3                      ret    
  4005de:   66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
```

We can see the offending lines that are responsible for the `usleep(10*1000*1000)` call:

```
  4005b9:   bf 80 96 98 00          mov    edi,0x989680
  4005be:   e8 cd fe ff ff          call   400490 <usleep@plt>
```

Since `0x989680` equals 10000000 in decimal, we can deduce that this is the argument for the `usleep()` function. So, we can just modify the binary (search for the byte sequence `bf 80 96 98 00 e8 cd fe ff ff`) and instead just put the `0x90` there for a `NOP` instruction, which does nothing.

Before and after:
[image: hex_comparison]

When we now dump the instructions:

```
root@kali:~/so# objdump -d -Mintel prog_cracked | grep  -A28 "<main>"
0000000000400596 <main>:
  400596:   55                      push   rbp
  400597:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40059a:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
  40059e:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
  4005a1:   48 89 75 f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
  4005a5:   bf 68 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x400668
  4005aa:   e8 a1 fe ff ff          call   400450 <puts@plt>
  4005af:   bf 90 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x400690
  4005b4:   e8 a7 fe ff ff          call   400460 <system@plt>
  4005b9:   90                      nop
  4005ba:   90                      nop
  4005bb:   90                      nop
  4005bc:   90                      nop
  4005bd:   90                      nop
  4005be:   90                      nop
  4005bf:   90                      nop
  4005c0:   90                      nop
  4005c1:   90                      nop
  4005c2:   90                      nop
  4005c3:   bf a2 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x4006a2
  4005c8:   e8 83 fe ff ff          call   400450 <puts@plt>
  4005cd:   bf 90 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x400690
  4005d2:   e8 89 fe ff ff          call   400460 <system@plt>
  4005d7:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4005dc:   c9                      leave  
  4005dd:   c3                      ret    
  4005de:   66 90                   xchg   ax,ax
```

Nice, the call is gone. Run and we get:

```
root@kali:~/so# chmod +x prog_cracked 
root@kali:~/so# ./prog_cracked 
Entry point. We'll now wait 10 seconds.
21:11:18
Woke up again.
21:11:18
```

And thus, the program is "cracked" again.